# How to disable page scroll when opening dialog box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dialog

I'm having significant trouble with a jquery dialog box that opens in response to a `.hover()` command, and closes upon leaving the hover (which of course takes two functions).

When the dialog box opens a little bit out of the page, the entire page scrolls up; I want to disable this but I can't figure out how.

I have tried:

1. using `event.preventDefault()`
2. putting the `ui-dialog` css as `'position: relative'`
3. setting the scroll bar back where it was (but this looks terrible)

Any other ideas?

Edit: Here is the code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TzUf3/1

Comment: Use http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/ instead of dialog

Comment: Where is the code? Make it up on jsfiddle.net, so we can see.

Comment: Alright, added a link to the code in jsfiddle. Thanks for that

Comment: Your jsFiddle is missing html/css, no way to test.

Comment: Gerr…you're right. I'll see what I can add. It's a 2000 line file...

Comment: Alright, added stuff to play around with. Gives the general idea. But I don't know if this gives a good idea of my problem at all...

Comment: Gotta click update and give us the new link :P should be like http://jsfiddle.net/TzUf3/1/ when you update.

Comment: Whoops! http://jsfiddle.net/TzUf3/1/

Comment: I'm with imdad. Might want to look into tooltips instead of dialogs for this. http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/

Comment: Alright, I'll check 'em out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the popup has its position fixed, then set the body to overflow:hidden;

When the dialogue is closed remove the overflow attribute.